# How do I get field names and the message name using nanopb in C?

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I need the message name and the field name of the protobuf in the form of a string.

I could not find a way to do this in nanopb's documentation.

Comment: If you feel the need to post the same question in [multiple places](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/issues/854), it is a good idea to link them together to avoid wasting other people's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nanopb does not have reflection (runtime introspection) support, as listed in [features and limitations](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/#features-and-limitations).

As such there is no API for accessing or iterating fields by their names.

At compile time, you can use the `FIELDLIST` [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) that is included in the generated `.pb.h` file. That can be used for autogenerating some things, such as list of strings for the field names.

The autogenerated list format is:

```
#define Person_FIELDLIST(X, a) \
X(a, STATIC,   REQUIRED, STRING,   name,              1) \
X(a, STATIC,   REQUIRED, INT32,    id,                2) \
X(a, STATIC,   OPTIONAL, STRING,   email,             3) \
X(a, STATIC,   REPEATED, MESSAGE,  phone,             4)
```

And access is by defining a macro:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define FIELDNAME_STR(a, atype, htype, ltype, fieldname, tag) STR(fieldname),

const char *fieldnames[] = {
    Person_FIELDLIST(FIELDNAME_STR, 0)
};
```

But there is quite little you can actually do with the field names, apart from printing out for logging and similar.

Comment: Thank you! Is there something I could do at the compiler level to generate macros with the message name?

Comment: And what name would you give to that macro? "MyMessage_name"? At that point you can as well just write `"MyMessage"`.